# Flink method undefined for certain type

Tags: java, apache-flink, mqtt, flink-streaming

I am a super newbie learning Apache Flink recently, I would like to build a program that achieves:

When I boardcast a string of number for example: 39 40 35 12 36 36 37 52 in Mqtt.fx (configuration code not shown, works fine), the java program I wrote below can exclude the outliers, here is 12 and 52, and then calculate the average number, this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);

        DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(new MqttConsumer());

        DataStream<Integer> dataStream = stream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Integer> out) throws Exception {
                String[] str = value.split(" ");
                int temperature = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
                out.collect(temperature);
            }
        }).setParallelism(1);

        

        DataStream<Integer> filteredDataStream = dataStream
                .filter(temperature -> temperature != findMaxTemperature(dataStream) && temperature != findMinTemperature(dataStream))
                .setParallelism(1);

        DataStream<Double> averageDataStream = filteredDataStream
                .map(temperature -> (double) temperature)
                .reduce(( t1,  t2) ->  t1 + t2)
                .map(sum -> sum / filteredDataStream.count())
                .setParallelism(1);

        averageDataStream.print();
        env.execute();
    }

    private static int findMaxTemperature(DataStream<Integer> dataStream) throws Exception {
        return dataStream.max(1).collect().get(0).getField(0);
    }

    private static int findMinTemperature(DataStream<Integer> dataStream) throws Exception {
        return dataStream.min(1).collect().get(0).getField(0);
    }
```

I also imported these pacakges:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
```

However, under `reduce`, there is an error: `The method reduce((<no type> t1, <no type> t2) -> {}) is undefined for the type SingleOutputStreamOperator<Double>`

Under `min` and `max`, it says: `The method max(int) is undefined for the type DataStream<Integer>`.

It seems to be some type converting problem, but I tried to revise it, I also tried to use `keyBy()`, which is said to be deprecated, and `maxBy()`, which also doesn't work. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: What's deprecated are the cases where keyBy and maxBy that have to use reflection. E.g., instead of `keyBy("id")` use `keyBy(event -> event.id)`.

Comment: Before you want to implement your function, it is recommended that you learn how to use various operators

Answer (score 0):

The way that you've tried to structure your application isn't going to work. As a stream processor, Flink is designed to process unbounded streams of data, and to process each event once. There's no way to determine the max and min elements of the stream without pre-processing the entire stream (whatever that means for an unbounded stream), so excluding the outliers is tricky business.

You could, instead, keep track of the max and min *seen so far in the input stream*, but excluding those won't make sense either.

For this particular application, perhaps you'd rather execute it in batch mode, in which case these issues will go away, and then the expected result will be well defined.

Answer (score 0):

As David noted, you can't find the min or max in an unbounded stream. If you must run this as a streaming job, you can use [Apache DataSketches](https://datasketches.apache.org/) to calculate a streaming/approximate quantile, and exclude values that are out-of-bounds. There is the boot-strapping problem, where you'd want to process and accumulate some number of values before you start filtering, to avoid false positives.